# Using mockFor to mock Sql.call() in a groovy unit test

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking

I'm trying to mock `newInstance()` and `call()` in groovy.sql.Sql:

```
package com.sample

import grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MySampleTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    void testThat_SqlCall_IsInvokedWithexpectedQuery() {
        def mockSql = new MockFor(Sql.class)

        mockSql.demand.newInstance { def datasource->
            return mockSql
        }

        mockSql.demand.call { def sql ->
            return 0
        }

        mockSql.use {
            MySample targetObject = new MySample()
            targetObject.myMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

Where this is the target code:

```
package com.sample

import groovy.sql.Sql

class MySample {
  def dataSource

  def myMethod() {
    def conn = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)
    conn.call("test")
  }
}
```

It errs out with:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [test]
```

The error makes it seem like the call() method is not being mocked. Is that the case? What's a fix for it?

Comment: I think the most pertinent missing data here are: (A) What unit testing framework are you using? And (B) What mocking library are you using? I may have more questions after that, but let's start there.

Comment: @BalRog - I'm using mockFor to do the mocking. According to the docs, it doesn't require an additional mocking library. Let me know if that's not the case. As far as the unit testing framework is concerned, I'm not sure that matters wrt this question, since the example fails without any validation code being present.

Comment: No, I expect you are correct on all counts. This is clearly one of the many parts of the Groovy API with which I am not familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `mockSql.demand.call` with `mockSql.metaClass.call` provides a mocked method, but requires manual verification that the method is called, and of the parameter values:

```
package com.sample

import grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MySampleTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    void testThat_SqlCall_IsInvokedWithexpectedQuery() {
        def mockSql = new MockFor(Sql.class)
        def callInvoked = 0

        mockSql.demand.newInstance { def datasource->
            return mockSql
        }

        mockSql.metaClass.call { def sql ->
            assert sql == "test"
            ++callInvoked
            return 0
        }

        mockSql.use {
            MySample targetObject = new MySample()
            targetObject.myMethod()
        }

        assert callInvoked == 1
    }
}
```

I don't know enough groovy yet to understand why this is the case, but it solved the issue for me.

Additional cosmetic changes plus moving the targetObject instantiation out of mySql.use {} result in:

```
package com.sample

import grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MySampleTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    MySample targetObject = new MySample()

    void testThat_SqlCall_IsInvokedWithexpectedQuery() {
        def mockSql = new MockFor(Sql)
        def callInvoked = 0

        mockSql.demand.newInstance { datasource->
            mockSql
        }

        mockSql.metaClass.call { sql ->
            assert sql == "test"
            ++callInvoked
            0
        }

        mockSql.use {
            targetObject.myMethod()
        }

        assert callInvoked == 1
    }
}
```